# How to assign or pass value to the instance variable in controller from rspec controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, associations

Following is my rails controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @client = (current_company.clients.size || 0) >= current_company.subscription.clients    # it returns true or false
    begin
      @obj = Class.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
      end
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

Following is my rspec code under (spec/controller):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyController do

  describe "GET index" do

    it "populates an array of data" do
       current_company = mock_model(CompaniesUser)
       clients = mock_model(Client)
       get :index

       .
       .
    end

  end

end
```

After execution it provide me following error:

```
Failures:

  1) MyController GET index populates an array of clients
     Failure/Error: get :index
       Double "Company_1" received unexpected message :clients with (no args)
     # ./app/controllers/my_controller.rb:20:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So how to do this association about `current_compnay.clients.size` in rspec controller? It provides an error due to not getting value `current_company.clients.size` in controller's index method from spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you looking for something like this?

```
it "populates an array of data" do
   controller.stub(:current_company) {
     mock_model(CompaniesUser, clients: [mock_model(Client)]) 
   }
   get :index
   # ...
```

Some changes after your comment:

```
let(:client) { mock_model(Client, :id => 1)}
let(:company) { mock_model(Company, :id => 1, :clients => [client])}
before { controller.stub(:current_company).and_return(company) }
it "populates an array of data" do
   get :index
   # ...
```

Comment: Yes SebastianG, i want this same kind of solution but your provided solution still not work. In my start of controller spec i defined current_user as follow
describe MyController do
let(:company) { mock_model(Company, :id => 1)}    
   controller.stub(:current_company).and_return(company)    
end

  describe "index" do
    it "populates" do
     :
     :
    end
   end
end    
now i want to define "clients" so in my index method i can get "current_company.clients.size" value.
please suggest me idea if you have.

Comment: You have to add an array of clients to mocked company. `mock_model(CompaniesUser, clients: [mock_model(Client)])` should do the trick. I added a slightly modified version of the code to meet your last comment. What exactely does not work? Still the previous error message?

Comment: I change little in your provided example and my issues has been resolved. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: please do not swallow errors!

what is that `begin` `rescue` `end` part for? please go ahead and remove that. it hides any error that occurs when rendering a template!

what is that `@obj = Class.all` is that pseudo code? if you add pseudo code, make a note about that!

if you have such complex logic in your controller, it would be a good idea to move it into a method of that class. so `(current_company.clients.size || 0) >= current_company.subscription.clients` might be refactored to a call of `current_company.has_not_enough_clients` or whatever your business logic should name it.

then go ahead and stub that method or use a test-double for only that specific model.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved as follow:

at start of controller spec:

```
let(:current_company) {mock_model(CompanyUser, :id => 1, clients: [mock_model(Client)])}
```

now you can access it as "current_company.clients.size" gives "1"

Comment: This is what I said. Why do you post the same instead of accepting my answer? I spent my time to help you, checking it as answer would be nice.

Comment: yes Sebastian, sorry for post answer but i posted without refresh my page in which you updated after my comment part. I accepted your answer. Thanks a lot